Movie or TV series with awesome wedding reception on rooftop; father has an attack after reception
This is a movie (maybe be a TV show) from probably the late 90's or up to '09. There is a very nice wedding reception on a rooftop (or at least outside), there are a lot of lights, may be blue and white, and it is awesomely decorated (nearly futuristic). 
I cannot remember the storyline, but I am pretty sure the movie is about the father of the bride and he is divorced with the mother, I think he had a very though life, but not sure who is the rich guy that paid for the reception as it seems like an expensive wedding. After the wedding, in the street, I think the father has an attack of some sort (not sure if he dies or not). The main actor was a well know guy, like Bruce Willis, Nicolas Cage, Robert De Niro, or Jack Nicholson. All I remember is the wedding scene was awesome; maybe the movie has a lot of years in between the start and end, perhaps a kind of life story. I am trying to remember hard what it is, and it is driving me nuts...so thanks for your help.

The reception might have looked a bit like this: http://www.allaboutvenuesblog.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Stunning-Wedding-Reception-sparkle-lights-centrepiece-by-Preston-Bailey.jpg

This kind of reminds me of Click (2006) with Adam Sandler. In the movie his life skips ahead due to the magic remote control he receives. At one point his life skips ahead to his daughter's futuristic wedding, and then it skips ahead to him in the hospital, where he falls down in the street, in the rain, due to a heart attack or something of the sort. 
Here is an image of the wedding scene from Click.


This made more sense to me than my suggestion (the wedding in Click has blue lights and it's outdoors), but then I realized that he visits his son's wedding in the future, not his daughter's. Maybe the OP got it wrong?

You're right! It was the son's wedding. I would guess that the OP just remembered wrong.

Yes surely this seems like it, I will have look, but I am pretty sure that is the one, thank you so much, is why I could not remember the story line too well as it "clicks" and has a hard time remembering what it was all about...but thanks so much, it is amazing how we are able to find out with that gigantic maze of memories!!!
